# Can someone convert this python to list comprehension?

Tags: python, unicode, list-comprehension

Can someone convert this python (2.7.2) to the equivalent one-liner?  This code works fine, but seems kinda extravagant for python.

```
for i in range(0,len(schema)):
        schema[i] = list(schema[i])
        for j in range(0,len(schema[i])):
            if isinstance(schema[i][j], unicode):
                schema[i][j] = str(schema[i][j])
```

I'm fumbling around with something like the following... but it obviously doesn't work.

```
[i = str(i) for i for sublist in schema for i in sublist if isinstance(i, unicode)]
```

For the record, I'm converting some sqlite schema info that doesn't need to be unicode formated, like this (the value of 'schema' that is):

```
[(0, u'course', u'VARCHAR(128)', 0, None, 0), ... (another tuple) ... ]
```

to strings, like this (if necessary the tuples can be converted to lists):

```
[(0, 'course', 'VARCHAR(128)', 0, None, 0), ... (another tuple) ... ]
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for `schema` and the desired output?

Comment: you probably just need to remove the `i =` at the beginning of your list comprehension, as you can't do assignments inside one. and, this isn't about lambdas at all - it's about list comprehensions, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Hyperboreus The data I posted is the value of schema, a list of tuples, one for each field of the table.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman You are probably right. I removed assignment, but the types didn't change. Perhaps because of tuple?  Can you enlighten me with a working answer?

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Updated question to be more accurate... i.e. not lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you actually want is a list comprehension which is not quite the same as a lambda

```
processed = [[val if not isinstance(val,basestring) else str(val) for val in row] for row in schema]
```

I think at least

Comment: Maybe a typo: `for row in for row`

Comment: +1 I was about to submit an identical solution, so I had the same interpretation.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks very much, works perfect.  Obviously so new to python that I couldn't recognize the difference between lambda and list compression.  Updated queston.  Will accept answer as soon as able to...